# Understanding regularization step in Meta-cell pre processing

Tags: scrnaseq, statistics, graphs

I'm reading through this paper: Baran, Y., Bercovich, A., Sebe-Pedros, A., Lubling, Y., Giladi, A., Chomsky, E., ... & Tanay, A. (2019). [MetaCell: analysis of single-cell RNA-seq data using K-nn graph partitions](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-019-1812-2). Genome biology, 20(1), 1-19.

[image]

Maybe I am not familiar with this notation but I don't understand the regularization procedure as follows:

1. What is happening in these max functions? What does the 0 indicate? They have some terms $x$ and then in the max function they write $max( x, 0)$.
2. I assume $K$ is some regularization parameter, like a cost. Is $s_{ij} * s_{ji}$ the rank product?  I.e. the geometric mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking in too much detail:

- We may suppose that $S$ is a matrix with dimensions indexed as $(i, j)$. So $s_{ij}$ is the cell of $S$ indexed to the $i$th row and $j$th column, and $s_{ji}$ is the cell vice versa. Therefore, symmetrizing $S$ is a matter of ensuring that $s_{ij} == s_{ji}$, which you can achieve by multiplying the (ranked?) entries. Symmetric matrices are nice for doing certain kinds of math, and yield a handy representation of undirected graphs, which the authors appear to be using for [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm).
- $max(x, 0)$ is just saying that you want either $x$ if $x$ is non-negative, or $0$ if it is negative. Thus, you make the whole matrix non-negative, which makes some handy matrix math possible. You can see how this works computationally by inspecting e.g. the Python `max()` [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).